# Symfony 2 : how to force path() method to add _format?

Tags: routes, symfony

I have a route defined as follows :

```
my_route:
  pattern: /{name}.{_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:Default:index, _format: html }
  requirements:
    _format: html
```

The problem is that when using the following code in a template (view) :

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route', {'name': 'my-name'}) }}">my link</a>
```

The generated URL is :

```
/my-name
```

But I want it to be :

```
/my-name.html
```

**without** having to specify it in my template...

Any idea ?

Thanks for your help,
Regards

Answer (score 3):

Can you not have:

```
my_route:
  pattern: /{name}.html
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:Default:index}
```

And

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route', {'name': 'my-name'}) }}">my link</a>
```

will give you url: /my-name.html

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Since you defined the default format to be `html`, there's no need for the router to generate a link with a `.html` extension.

If you really want the extension to be displayed, you should remove it from the `defaults` list. The downside is that you must always specify the format for this route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is that I need to force the "html" extension to be here for SEO reason. So, is there another way to change the router behavior ?

Comment: @user1018527 Well, there's no easy solution as the `_format` value is not in any way special. You would have to fork the `Routing` component and make the changes yourself, which is not that trivial. Here's the relevant [function](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Generator/UrlGenerator.php#L98). In my opinion it would be easier to remove the `_format` parameter from the `defaults` list.

Answer (score 0):

An old question, but if anyone is looking for a way to generate with the default value still, Symfony have a new(ish) way to achieve this. From the [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-parameters):

> If you want to always include some default value in the generated URL
> (for example to force the generation of `/blog/1` instead of `/blog` in
> the previous example) add the ! character before the parameter name:
> `/blog/{!page}`

So in your example in the yaml file just add the `!` like so:

```
my_route:
  pattern: /{name}.{!_format}
  defaults: { _controller: AcmeMyBundle:Default:index, _format: html }
  requirements:
    _format: html
```

This way you can add to the requirements such as `html|json|xml` but still always generate the default route with `html`.

Answer (score -2):

Is this going to help (tested and it works for me)?

```
<a href="{{ path('my_route', {'name': 'my-name'}) }}.html">my link</a>
```